# Why is it incorrect to say that KE of COM is not the same as total KE? Does this also apply to PE?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, energy-conservation

I sort of understand why KE(com) is not the same as KE(total)... correct me if I'm wrong.. its like when a symmetric body is performing rotational motion even though the COM is not moving it still has (Rotational) kinetic energy. But does this translate to potential energy or can you calculate PE be considering the COM?

Answer (score 2):

For an extended body in a *uniform* gravitational field, its potential energy is the same as that of a point mass located at the bodies' center of mass.  This can be seen by writing out the total gravitational potential energy in terms of the gravitational potential energies of its constituent masses:
$$
U = \sum_{i} m_i g z_i = g \sum_i m_i z_i
$$
where $z$ is the "vertical" coordinate and the sum runs over all of the masses in the body (perhaps as an integral for a continuous body.)  But by the $z$-coordinate of the center of mass is
$$
z_{CM} = \frac{\sum_i m_i z_i}{M} \quad \Rightarrow \quad M z_{CM} = \sum_i m_i z_i
$$
where $M$ is the total mass of the body;  and so $U = M g z_{CM}$ for the body.

Note, however, that the same argument does not hold if the gravitational field is not uniform.  For example, you cannot say that the gravitational potential energy of a hypothetical [space elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) is the same as the gravitational potential energy of a point mass at its center of mass, since the acceleration due to gravity varies substantially over the length of the object.

Comment: However, isn't "center of gravity" then useful for an object in a non-uniform gravitational field? Would that be useful to include here?

Comment: @BioPhysicist:  It's not immediately obvious to me that the "center of gravity" as conventionally defined (a point at which the *force* can be said to act) is equivalent to a "center of gravitational potential energy" (a point at which the *potential energy* of a point mass is equal to the potential energy of the extended body.)   I'll have to run a calculation or two.

Comment: After calculation: they're not equivalent.  Consider a rod of mass $m$ and uniform density extending from $r$ to $2r$ in the gravitational field of a body of mass $M$.  The center of gravity is that point $r_{CG}$ for which the total force on the rod is equal to $G M m/{r_{CG}^2}$;  after some calculation, we find that $r_{CG} = \sqrt{2} r$.  On the other hand, if we say the "center of potential energy" $r_{CPE}$ is that point for which the total potential energy is $G M m/r_{CPE}$, one can show that $r_{CPE} = r/\ln 2$.

Comment: Ah ok cool, thanks.